# How efficient does io.emit send data?

Tags: socket.io

We are using socket.io for some realtime message broadcasting.

Imagine we have 10 connected clients.

on the server side we send a message with io.emit(„channel1“,payload).

only 1 connected client listens for a message ‚channel1‘ by calling
socket.on(‚channel1‘,function()...)

is the message really sent to all 10 clients, or is it only sent to the 1 client which listens to channel1?

if the message is sent to all 10 clients we would have a big overhead, because the other 9 clients would ignore the message at all.

or should we use namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it will send it to everyone but if you want to send it to a specific channel then you will need to [emit to the namespace](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/), which is, essentially, just an end point. If you would like to try this out then there is a good chrome extension [Firecamp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firecamp-a-campsite-for-d/eajaahbjpnhghjcdaclbkeamlkepinbl)

if you are familiar with Observables then Observables are like implementations of Websockets. You subscribe to an event (like you would in JavaScript `.addEventListener()` and then it just sits there.. and waits... and waits.. and then *BOOM* it gets a signal to listen and act upon the data. I hope this cleared it up, if not then I'll edit for more information